# C# GIF encoder/decoder

Tags: c#, encoding, gif, decoding

I’m working on a program that loads a animated GIF file and alter some of the pixels, then spits it back out as a new animated GIF file. The outputted GIF animates just fine in Windows, browsers and Photoshop.

However, if I try to load the GIF with my program, it will not animated. Also, I cannot get the correct palette. The loading code is exactly the same code that I use to load the original GIF with in the first place.

Here’s my saving code:

```
   public int saveAsGif(string absPath, byte[] mark)
    {
        BitmapPalette palette = new BitmapPalette(getPaletteAsMediaColorList(m_Pal));

        int width = m_CanvasWidth;
        int height = m_CanvasHeight;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(absPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            GifBitmapEncoder encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();

            for (int f = 0; f < m_NumberOfFrames; f++)
            {
                FrameData frame = m_Frames[f];
                byte[] pixels = frame.pixels;

                BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
                    width,
                    height,
                    96,
                    96,
                    System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8,
                    palette,
                    pixels,
                    width);

                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));

            }
            encoder.Save(fs);

            fs.Close();
        }

        return RESULT_SUCCESFUL;
    }
```

To make sure it's not my loading code, I created a plain new project with the following code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap test1 = new Bitmap(@"F:\original.gif");
        pictureBox1.Image = test1;

        Bitmap test2 = new Bitmap(@"F:\exported.gif");
        pictureBox2.Image = test2;
    }
```

original.gif will load and play perfectly, exported.gif will only show a still frame. However, in Windows/Browser/Photoshop exported.gif will play.

Comment: ` if I try to load the GIF with my program, it will not animated` , which control are you using to display it ? If used even a normal picturebox, it will still show the animation

Comment: "The outputted GIF animates just fine in Windows, browsers and Photoshop." So it's being created just fine. I don't think the code you are showing us is an issue.

Comment: "If used even a normal picturebox, it will still show the animation": That does not work for the exported GIF. I have updated my initial post with a load example. All GIF (except for ones I exported with above code) will load and play just fine.

Comment: This really feels like an issue with picturebox where it's not as forgiving as every other gif renderer you are trying it on for the converted gif. Suggesting that you gif isn't perfect, but close enough for everything but picturebox. I'm curious if it has something to do with the the bitmap for each frame. 96dpi is a curious choice, but I don't think it will affect the gif since gifs don't care about dpi. Perhaps set to 72 anyway and see what happens. Furthermore your stride is incorrect. Stride is the number of bytes for one line of the bitmap, or `(width * pixels.BitsPerPixel + 7)/8`

Comment: It might be worth tweaking those just to see if it makes PictureBox happy. Totally guessing here though as everything looks ok and you are getting a gif written and displaying everywhere but the PictureBox control.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! After some research I suspect GifBitmapEncoder does not correctly (or not at all) write the Graphic Control Extension (which includes frame times among others). I suspect that other decoders might just fill in default values (say 100 ms delay per frame) when not being able to find the Graphic Control Extension block, while PictureBox might be more picky like you suggest.

Comment: Side note: from my experience, `Bitmap` class has some trouble interpreting animated gifs correctly. They load, and you can access the frames, but it'll see it as a 32bppARGB format, and not indexed, and you can't get the palette.

Comment: Hi guys, I found an awesome solution which i added to the main post!

Comment: @user1753782: You should add your solution as an answer to the post. It might seem a bit weird if you are new to the site but that's the way stack overflow works. People can then upvote it to show community support for the answer and it works better for stack's systems (eg currently it considers this question as unanswered). Good you found an answer though!

Comment: Thanks! I have added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a relative simple solution. It’s not perfect, but it worked for me. It works with GifBitmapEncoder only, no additional libraries are needed.

All that you need to do;

1. write the GIF data from encoder to a memory stream.
2. Binary write the first 13 bytes (GIF89a header and stuff).
3. Binary write the ‘ApplicationExtention’ block.
4. Binary write the rest of the GIF data.

The ApplicationExtention block allows for animations. If no delay times are set, the default time of 100ms is used. If you do want custom delays for each frame, you will need to add a few more bytes in between (see GIF file format doc).

Code:

```
public void saveAsGif(string absPath)
{
    int width = m_CanvasWidth;
    int height = m_CanvasHeight;

    GifBitmapEncoder encoder = new GifBitmapEncoder();
    BitmapPalette palette = new BitmapPalette(getPaletteAsMediaColorList(m_Pal));

    for (int f = 0; f < m_NumberOfFrames; f++)
    {
        FrameData frame = m_Frames[f];
        byte[] pixels = frame.pixels;

        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            96,
            96,
            System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed8,
            palette,
            pixels,
            width);

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    }

    byte[] GifData;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        GifData = ms.ToArray();
    }

    byte[] ApplicationExtention = { 33, 255, 11, 78, 69, 84, 83, 67, 65, 80, 69, 50, 46, 48, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0 };

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(absPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(GifData, 0, 13);
        fs.Write(ApplicationExtention, 0, ApplicationExtention.Length);
        fs.Write(GifData, 13, GifData.Length - 13);
    }
}
```